# Modify the Optional<Person> if present

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a scenario where I am getting an `Optional<Person> person` from the DB and I need to modify the `person` as `person.setRole("Admin")` if the person is present and set it in my `MainClass.java`.

I tried :

```
var p = person.map(person1 -> person1.setRole("Admin"));
```

but this seems incorrect.
I want to update the same object and not create a new one.

**EDIT:**

After setting the value I need to set this person object as it is member variable in Department class.

```java
@Builder //lombok
class Department {
    private Long depId;
    private Person person;
}
```

MainClass.java

```java
Department.builder()
          .depId(1L)
          .person( The person that I will get from the operation I need )
          .build()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `person.ifPresent(person1 -> person1.setRole("Admin"));` without another assignment.

Comment: I need to set this `person` in another department object. If I am using `ifPresent` it will return me `void` which is not my ideal scenario. Please check the EDIT of the question.

Comment: Duplicate question on Optional. Map only executes "if present" and returns an optional. If you want a person object returned then also add ".orElse" or something like that to throw an exception or provide a default value.  I'm sure if you check around SO then you will find this carefully expored.

Comment: You changed the question. What you want to do after you executed `setRole("Admin")` has nothing to do with what you asked before. Your `map` approach did not serve your new task better than `ifPresent`.

Comment: @Holger excuse my ignorance but I cannot put `person.ifPresent(person1 -> person1.setRole("Admin"))` in the builder() because this returns `void` and I need `person`. Not sure what I am missing here. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Before your edit, you didn’t say that you want to pass something to a builder. Your posted attempt, `var p = person.map(person1 -> person1.setRole("Admin"));` still has no connection to that builder attempt. And there is no reason why these two things should be mixed. You want to invoke `setRole("Admin")` when the optional is not empty, `person.ifPresent(person1 -> person1.setRole("Admin"));` will do that. Then, you want to pass the person to a builder, no problem, but you have to decide what to do when the optional is empty. E.g., as K.Nicholas said, `orElse` is one way if you have a fallback

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation. I now understood my mistake. I was thinking that I need to do `setRole("Admin")` and then I need to store that value in a variable. What I missed was that I am already modifying the original object so there was no need of `var p` and directly could do `person.orElse` in the builder. This makes sense now. Thanks for all the time you took to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified what you want to do if the Optional is empty. Since there are no `@Builder.Default` on top of `person`, I assume that you want to keep it as `null` when the optional is empty.

You could provide the `ifPresent` first to set the role. It would be executed only if value is present, otherwise does nothing.
Then pass the object by invoking `orElse` on this object to the builder.

```java
optPersonFromDb.ifPresent(p -> p.setRole("Admin"));
Department.builder()
          .depId(1L)
          .person(optPersonFromDb.orElse(null))
          .build();
```